# Project bye bye Adobe tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Since mostly all questions focus around Adobe software I'm hoping to encourage an initiative to audit/removal of any Q&A tagged with [adobe](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe).  As I [mentioned](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44664013#44664013) in chat:

> just a suggestion. If anyone has less then 2k rep and looking to gain
>   rep I'd strongly advise editing posts that have the adobe tag so we
>   can destroy that tag. It would be a good time to see what else the
>   question may need and if it hasn't been answered or has an accepted
>   answer it could help those Q&As.

**If you see a question come through the Que for a tag removal please do not reject the edit.**  I would also like to encourage anyone removing a tag, if it's only Adobe, and adding a better tag.  For example [adobe-certified-expert](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-certified-expert) was created for ACE related questions rather than using [adobe](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe).

Comment: Here's a query to find [questions tagged with adobe only](https://data.stackexchange.com/graphicdesign/query/853186/questions-tagged-with-adobe-only). Bear in mind SEDE works with old data, so changes made now don't show up for a few days.

Comment: Also helpful: [Questions tagged with *adobe* but no other adobe-related tag](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Badobe%5D+-%5Badobe-%2A%5D+closed%3Ano+migrated%3Ano+deleted%3Ano).

Comment: A lot of folks refer to Adobe Acrobat as just Adobe (and tag it as such), so use your judgement to see if that's what they're talking about.

Comment: 0 questions tagged! yay \o/ \o/ \o/

Comment: … and the tag is blacklisted.